# How to set custom view for day in CalendarView?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing some Android application, and now I've got the following problem: for some days I need to set custom view, but I haven't found any examples of this feature. I hoped  that there was some adapters for CalendarView, but it's false. Please, tell me, how can I do it? Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: I use CalendarView in Android 4.0 (default component)